# UITextField inside UIColletionViewCell becomeFirstResponder

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield, uicollectionviewcell

I know this question might have a lot of answers on SO. But after trying every solution found on the interweb (+ some of my custom inventions ..) I still can't do what I want to achieve.

Here is the story :

I have a UICollectionViewCell with a Subclass of a UITextField embeded in it.

Here is my Subclass :

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    private let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 2.0)

    private lazy var lineView: UIView = {
        let lineView = UIView()
        lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lineView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        lineView.frame.size.height = 2
        lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.tiara
        return lineView
    }()

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }
    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func toggleColors() {
        if isFirstResponder {
            lineView.backgroundColor = .black
        } else {
            lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.tiara
        }
    }
}

private extension CustomTextField {
    func commonInit() {
        addSubview(lineView)
        constraintLineView()
        textColor = UIColor.tiara
    }

    func constraintLineView() {
        lineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        lineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
        lineView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        lineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2.0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

And here is the code I use in my UICollectionViewCell :

```
@discardableResult
func setFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return customTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

func endEditing() {
    customTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

The result of customTextField.becomeFirstResponder is always `false`.

It's called from my UIViewController :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard indexPath.row != 0 else { return }

    dispatchService.stop()
    let topIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

    let topCell: Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: topIndexPath)
    topCell.endEditing()
    service.data.rearrange(from: indexPath.row, to: 0)
    update()

    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        collectionView.moveItem(at: indexPath, to: topIndexPath)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: topIndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }) { (_) in
        let secondCell: Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: topIndexPath)
        secondCell.setFirstResponder()
        self.dispatchService.reset()
    }
}
```

I really don't know where to start, this is the last solution I came with and it stills stays without any keyboard displayed.

I am working on a real device, iPhone X iOS 12.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not have the quiet right answer but, I think the problem comes from the way you are getting your cell inside `collectionView(didSelectItemAt:)`.

You are using the `dequeueReusableCell` instead of using `cellForItem(at:)` for getting your cells. So you are creating a reusable cell and not getting the one you are interested in.